# Tree.js ';' expected. ts(1005)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on putting together a tutorial that I'm following on three.js and Vanilla.js I have this problem with the first line `onscroll(){ is expected a ';'`, but doesn't make any sense to me. It seems that there is a problem with Typescript or something. I really appreciate your help.

```
onscroll(){
 window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
       
 if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            this.lerp.target += 0.01;
            this.back = true;
 } else {
            this.lerp.target -= 0.01;
            this.back = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `function onscroll() { ... }`? It isn't a valid function declaration as it is. If it's a method within a larger class, that'd be helpful to know as well. Aligned indentation would probably help with debugging as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `function` in front of `onscroll()`

```
function onscroll() {
  window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      this.lerp.target += 0.01;
      this.back = true;
    } else {
      this.lerp.target -= 0.01;
      this.back = false;
    }
  });
}
```

If you want to define a function without `function` key, you can use [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
const onscroll = () => {
  window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      this.lerp.target += 0.01;
      this.back = true;
    } else {
      this.lerp.target -= 0.01;
      this.back = false;
    }
  });
};
```